# Subtract 2D array from 4D array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a greyscale image, represented by a 2D array of integers, shape (1000, 1000).

I then use `sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d()` to generate an array of 3x3 'patches' from this image, resulting in an array of shape (1000000, 3, 3), as there are 1 million 3x3 arrays for each pixel value in the original image.

I reshape this to (1000, 1000, 3, 3), which is a 1000x1000 array of 3x3 arrays, one 3x3 array for each pixel in the original image.

I now want to effectively subtract the 2D array from the 4D array. I have already found a method to do this, but I would like to make one using vectorisation.

I currently iterate through each pixel and subtract the value there from the 3x3 array at the same index. This is a little bit slow.

This is what currently loads images, formats the arrays before hand, and then performs this subtraction.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from skimage import io
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
import numpy

jitter = 1
patchsize = (jitter*2)+1

#load image as greyscale image using PIL
original = load_image_greyscale(filename)

#create a padded version of the image so that 1000x1000 patches are made
#instead of 998x998
padded = numpy.asarray(ImageOps.expand(original,jitter))

#extract these 3x3 patches using sklearn
patches = image.extract_patches_2d(padded,(patchsize,patchsize))

#convert image to numpy array
pixel_array = numpy.asarray(original)

#then reshape the array of patches so it matches array_image
patch_array = numpy.reshape(patches, (pixel_array.shape[0],pixel_array.shape[1],patchsize,patchsize))
#create a copy for results
patch_array_copy = numpy.copy(patch_array)

#iterate over each 3x3 array in the patch array and subtract the pixel value
#at the same index in the pixel array
for x in range(pixel_array.shape[0]):
    for y in range(pixel_array.shape[1]):
        patch_array_copy[x,y] = patch_array[x,y] - pixel_array[x,y]
```

I would like a way to perform the final step in the for loop using matrix operations.

I would also like to extend this at some point to work with RGB images, effectively making it a subtraction of an array with shape(1000,1000,3) from an array with shape(1000,1000,3,3,3). But i'm trying to go one step at a time here.

Any help or tips or suggestions or links to helpful resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up broadcasting in NumPy.

Comment: Just do `patch_array_copy = patch_array - pixel_array[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]`.

Comment: @jdehesa oh wow it was that simple. I feel bad. thankyou!

Comment: @jdehesa would extending it to RGB be as simple as `patch_array_copy = patch_array - pixel_array[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]`?

Comment: @mattrea6 Yes, you may have a look at [how broadcasting works](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Essentially, any 1-sized dimension can be automatically tiled, and dimensions "to the left" can be added automatically. Since the additional dimensions here are "to the right", we need to add new 1-sized dimensions to `pixel_array`, which can be done easily by indexing with `np.newaxis` (in actuality `np.newaxis` is just `None`, so `pixel_array[:, :, None, None]` does the same but less readable, and there is also `np.expand_dims` that does the same).

Comment: @jdehesa Brilliant! Thanks very much for this. This whole operation used to take ~50 seconds on a 1000x1000 px image, now it's blindingly fast!